# MySQL join query to link valuations with associated valuation tasks

Tags: performance, mysql, database, join

```
SELECT v.valuation_id
FROM valuation v
LEFT JOIN valuation_task vt
on vt.valuation_id = v.valuation_id 
      AND vt.valuation_task_id = 
        (
           SELECT valuation_task_id
           FROM valuation_task y
           WHERE y.valuation_id = v.valuation_id AND y.valuation_task_name = 'Listing live' AND y.valuation_task_status = '3'
        )
```

For each valuation (valuation_id), I want to search the valuation_task table, for a task with the attributes taskname = 'Listing live' and task status = '3' (which means the task is completed). There are approximately 8 valuation tasks against each valuation. The query takes over a minute to execute which is obviously unworkable.

Screenshot of the valuation_task table attached. There are 15069 rows in the valuation_task table and circa 2000 rows in the valuation table.

Happy to provide any further information required.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What immediately caught my eye is the naming of the table's columns. All `valuation_task_*` prefixes are redundant and should be removed, since the table is already called `valuation_task`. Hence it is obvious, that a field `id` would constitute the `valuation_task`'s id.

Comment: Thanks @RichardNeumann, I will keep that in mind. Would changing the field names improve the speed of the query?

Comment: No. Certainly not. It would just improve the query readability imho.

Comment: I also wonder why you do this weird sub-query, which most likely is responsible for the performance penalty. Can't you just slap the `WHERE` clause onto the outer select?
It's difficult to judge whether that'll provide the desired result, since I don't know what your're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I have just added more information to the question with regards to what I'm trying to achieve. I can't put a WHERE clause on the outer select and the query needs to know what valuation_task to join to in the first instance. There are 8 valuation tasks against each valuation

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  It's best to describe **what value this code provides to its user**.

Comment: @TobySpeight No problem, I have done that

Comment: Thanks for that.  I should have also recommended that include the definition of your tables and indexes (without which it's hard to give a good review, especially for 'performance' questions) as SQL statements, so that reviewers can reproduce your test environment.